# Why does my React functional component fail to rerender when I change a (boolean) state property value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple React component that renders a div that is a grid container of 2 rows and 2 columns. It also renders a button.

I have an array of JSX for four divs of red background that I put in the grid.

I have another array of JSX for four divs of yellow background that I want to go into the grid instead of the red ones when I click a button.

To force a re-render I am changing the value of a state property in the onClick handler of the button.

The problem is that when I click the button the squares in the grid don't change from the red ones to the yellow ones. The red ones remain there.

Here's my code:

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import React from 'react';
import './styles.css';


export default function MyComponent() {

// state property that code will change 
// to force a rerender:
const [rerender, setRerender] = useState(false)

// ref that code reads to conditionally
// render the squares in the grid div: 
const whatToShowInGrid = useRef(0)


let myArray = [1,2,3,4]

// The red squares get put into array displaySquares:
let displaySquares  = myArray.map(member=> <div className="divRedBackground" key={member} ></div>)
 
// The yellow squares get put into array displaySquares1:
let displaySquares1 = myArray.map(member=> <div className="divYellowBackground" key={member} ></div>)


// click handler for the button:
function changeSquaresInGrid(){
console.log(`You clicked the button!`)

// Simply toggle the value of whatToShowInGrid.current
// from 0 to 1:
    if (whatToShowInGrid.current === 0) {
        whatToShowInGrid.current = 1
                                        }

    if (whatToShowInGrid.current === 1) {
        whatToShowInGrid.current = 0
                                        }

// force a rerender by toggling the value of 
// state property rerender from false to true:
setRerender(!rerender)
                           }


    return (
      <>
      {/*The grid container*/}
      <div className='gridContainer'>
      { whatToShowInGrid.current === 0 ? <>{displaySquares}</> : <>{displaySquares1}</> }   
      </div>


      {/*The button*/}
      <div className="button1" onClick={changeSquaresInGrid}>
        <p className="button1Text">Click me</p>
      </div>
      </>
           );

                                 }
```

Comment: Instead of having two sets of divs why not just have one set and then change their background colour when the button is clicked?

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. turned out that the if statements in the onClick  handler were wrong. I have deleted my question out of shame!

Comment: @alienCred you can delete your question if you wish but please don't deface it (it's against site rules). I've rolled back your edit. There's no harm in realizing a question was trivial, it happens to all of us, just delete it or leave it alone.

Comment: thank you, Jared. how do I delete it (he asked red-facedly)?

Comment: @alienCred now that it has an answer you can't, just accept Andy's answer (green checkmark) and let it go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having two sets of divs why not just have *one* set and then change their background colour when the button is clicked.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  // Initialise state to red
  const [ background, setBackground ] = useState('red');

  // Create a set of boxes
  function createGrid() {
    return [1, 2, 3, 4].map(el => {
      const id = el + 1;
      const cn = ['box', background].join(' ');
      return <div key={id} data-id={id} className={cn}></div>;
    });
  }

  // Function to toggle between red and yellow
  // and set the new state
  function switchBackground() {
    setBackground(prev => prev === 'red' ? 'yellow' : 'red');
  }

  // Return a grid of boxes, and a button
  return (
    <main>
      <section className="grid">
        {createGrid()}
      </section>
      <button type="button~" onClick={switchBackground}>
        Switch background
      </button>
    </main>
  );

}

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<Example />);
```

```css
.grid { width: 100px; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr; gap: 2px; margin-bottom: 1rem;}
.box { width: 50px; aspect-ratio: 1; }
.red { background-color: red; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
button:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```